# What is this mnist download error? (python)

Tags: python

I am eager to self-learn deep-learning with tutorial books. Almost every book has an example of mnist, and I am having a hard time to load the data.
The book I am using is "Deep-learning with scratch". The recommended code is below.

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.pardir)
from dataset.mnist import load_mnist
```

I've created the folder "dataset" in the same location with my code file, and downloaded the source code "mnist.py" to the dataset folder.

and the error message is as below.
Please help me on this.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/hyyoon/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       from dataset.mnist import load_mnist
>
> File "/Users/hyyoon/STUDY_Machine_2019/dataset/mnist.py", line 7
>       
>       ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: At least you can provide `mnist.py` file itself for others to look into the problem.

Comment: The error is in this "mnist.py" file that you didn't post (or linked to or whatever) so no one can tell what the real problem is. But chances are it's not for the same Python version as you are using...

Answer (score 0):

You did not give any details on what framework you're working with (`skearn`? `tensorflow`?  `keras`?, ... )

But since you said 'deep learning', I guess it might be keras or tensorflow. Please edit your post with 1) more details on what you are working with 2) tags reflecting that as well.

As for keras, it might look like this:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

... 

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```